# What does count(1) in SQL mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sql-null

```
select patientID, count(1)    
from dbo (nolock)    
where admissiontime between '2020-01-31' and '2020-02-01'

patientID in (0, 1)

/*
0 means arthritis

1 means asthma
*/
```

So above query is used to find how many times there was a request from hospital for both asthma and arthritis related case.

It is put in a group by the `patientID`, but does that `count(1)` mean it counts everything patientID?

Comment: please, post actual query, this one make no sense  (group by, dbo as a table?)....

Comment: [Stop splattering nolock everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). You shouldn't need to be told this multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `count(1)` produces just the same result as `count(*)`: that is, it counts the number of records in the group defined by the `group by` clause.

Why? `count(<expr>)` counts every non-`null`  value of `<expr>`. Here it is given a constant value, `1`, that is never `null` - so it counts all rows.

I wouldn't recommend `count(1)`; checking for nullity of each and every row requires more work for the database that just counting all rows. Some databases might optimize `count(1)` as `count(*)` under the hood (as it is obvious that this fixed expression will never be `null`), but why bother, when you can optimize yourself already? Just use `count(*)` consistently.

Comment: both count(1) and count(*) are the same.   Count(1) was to make sure there's no NULL value, but now count(*) does the same thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1-sql-server   
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @MLeblanc by "now" do you mean "since the 1990s"? :-)

Comment: exactly, the semantic meaning goes away using count(1) which says-> count the number of (1) in a table, why stop at  1?, you could use count(42),count(3),count(4) as well. However count(*) -> count all the records in the table. * meaning the wildcard for "all"

Comment: @AaronBertrand  i was taught at university (in the early 2000) that count(*) would fetch all rows and  would count only rows that have at least one non-null value, and since your table should have PK, that made no sense to do a count(*).  But I was curious and take a  look at standard sql-92,sql-89 and sql-86 and they all stated that "If COUNT(*) is specified, then the result is the cardinality of R. ".  So, i guess "now" mean "since the beginning"  :-)